# Identifying features that are surrounded by a certain dimension of another polygon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, overlapping-features, adjacency

I am currently working on a project where I have two polygons files overlapping each over - Polygon A (blue) overlaps Polygon B (green). I would like to be able to identify the individual "blue" features in Polygon A that meet the following criteria:

Are surrounded by at least 500ft of green on any side

Has anyone tried something similar, or have any suggestions on a route that may be successful?[image]

Comment: Side definition is missing

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  Since you say "a separate solution is needed for each of the criteria", I think you are asking two questions.

Comment: There was no difference between the two criteria. Since this is a basic buffer problem, but can be solved be either a negative or positive buffer (on the appropriate layer), it seems you need to make an attempt to solve the task before asking a Question.

Comment: Intersect the layers, calculate perimiter length, join the result back to the blue polygons, select by attribute